# Como faço pra calcular distância euclidiana

Tags: java, encapsulamento

Tenho uma classe `Ponto`:

```
public class Ponto {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Tenho que criar um método "distancia" que receba outra instância por parâmetro e calcula a
distância euclidiana entre o ponto encapsulado e o ponto passado por argumento.

*Como calcula a distância euclidiana:*

Sejam os pontos 
A=(Xa, Ya) 
B=(Xb, Yb)

então a distancia dá-se por

d² = (Xa-Xb)² + (Ya-Yb)²

Isolando:

d = raiz ( (Xa-Xb)² + (Ya-Yb)² )

**Problema: como faço pra calcular isso no algoritmo?**

Comment: você está com dificuldade em algum ponto em específico do seu código? você já tem a formula, já tem tudo, basta implementar

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer assim:

```
  public int distancia(Ponto p){
      //algoritmo que calcula distancia entre (this.x, this.y)
      //e (p.getX(), p.getY()) passados como argumento Ponto p.
  }
```